# String between php

Tags: php, string, html, between

I've got something like this:

```
$string = '<some code before><div class="abc">Something written here</div><some other code after>'
```

What I want is to get what is within the div and output it:

```
Something written here
```

How can I do that in php? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `echo strip_tags($string);`

Comment: Just using strip_tags() might leave some of the `<other code>`s' content as well...

Comment: @BlueBockser without a more detailed question, we have no idea whether `<some code before>` contains content that would be left or not.... as the question stands, it doesn't

Comment: As written, <some code before> and <some other code after> contain code that has to be deleted and not shown.

Comment: As written, `<some code before>` and `<some other code after>` willl be removed completely by `strip_tags()`.... if `<some other code after>` was actually `<div>some more text</div>, then `some more text` would be retained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the DOMDocument class.

```
// HTML document stored in a string
$html = '<strong><div class="abc">Something written here</div></strong>';

// Load the HTML document
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

// Find div with class 'abc'
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query('//div[@class="abc"]');

// Echo the results...
if($result->length > 0) {
    foreach($result as $node) {
        echo $node->nodeValue,"\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "Empty result set\n";
}
```

Read up on the [expression syntax for XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) to customize your DOM searches.